# Binance smart chain node API provider without billing per websocket response

Tags: web3js, web3-providers, binance-smart-chain, explorer-api, api

I'm unsure if this is the correct place to ask but I thought I'd try anyway.

**Problem**

I want to build a Node.js application using the Web3 library. The application should collect prices on liquidity pools on PancakeSwap in real-time. To do that, I want to receive IUniswapV2Pair Sync events directly from the blockchain (Binance mainnet) over a WebSocket connection **without**  using any third-party token pricing APIs.
Since I would like to add a couple of hundred liquidity pools, I have to subscribe to quite a few events.

I have tried a few popular providers, such as [QuickNode](https://www.quicknode.com/), [ChainStack](https://chainstack.com/), and [GetBlock](https://getblock.io/) but they **use up credits per WebSocket response** (which is sometimes quite hidden because a "request" in their terms can also mean a WebSocket response).

**Question**

Is there a provider that **doesn't bill per WebSocket response** but only **per request that I make** (or something similar) so I don't have to pay more when more transactions are made? Ideally, it should also support other chains but Binance smart chain would be enough.

Or do I have to run my own light node to perform this kind of task?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage dedicated nodes on Chainstack with [unlimited calls included](https://support.chainstack.com/hc/en-us/articles/4402611570713-Elastic-and-dedicated-nodes)